# Isosceles Trapezoid Diagonal Lengths

Tags: geometry

In isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$, $AB=6$, $BC=9$, $CD=8$, and $AD=9$ find the distance from point $D$ to $BC$ (perpendicular).

Comment: i have only tried making a drawing

Comment: and i also tried with pythagorean thm but it is dirty

Comment: @Geo: Good! Making a drawing is the first step, and applying Pythagorean Theorem is essential (or, at least, very useful).

Comment: But i need help!

Comment: don't get it at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some questions you should be able to answer, which will help you to find the answer you're looking for.

1. What is the distance from $AB$ to $CD$? (*Hint*: Use Pythagorean Theorem.)
2. What is the area of triangle $BCD,$ given the answer to the first question?
3. If we consider $BC$ as the "base" of the triangle $BCD,$ what is the answer to your question, given the answer to the second question? (*Hint*: Try rotating your picture. What is the height of the triangle $BCD$ if $BC$ is the base?)

If you have trouble answering any of these questions, let me know, but give them your best shot.

Comment: 1. sqrt (80) 2. 2 sqrt(5) 3.

Comment: Actaully. I dont know how to do 2 and 3

Comment: Well (as for part 2), what is the height of $BCD$? What is the base? You were given one of these, and found the other. Use your picture.

Comment: 16 sqrt(5)  is the area

Comment: but wait, we arent looking for BD, though.

Comment: Correct! Now, it's true that we weren't *asked* for $BD,$ but it still turns out to help us. Stay with me, and find $BD.$

Comment: BD^2 = 7^2 + (4 sqrt(5))^2 = sqrt(129)

Comment: I mean BD = sqrt (129)

Comment: Excellent! And I just now realized I'm leading you down the wrong trail. That approach was going to give you the perpendicular distance from $C$ to $BD,$ which isn't what was asked for. (That's what I get for not drawing a picture!) Disregard $BD.$ Let me edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: ok thanks, keep me posted as you solve

Comment: Answer fixed. Can you finish the problem now?

Comment: no, sorry im not sure what to do

Comment: Think on it. I've added another hint, if you need it.

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUU!!!!!!!!!!!!! (32 sqrt (5))/9 !!!!!!!!

Comment: wait, then BD is pretty much useless?

Comment: Yes, at least for this problem. That was a bit of dyslexia on my part. :-P

Comment: Nice answer and lots of patience (+1)

Answer (score 1):

A picture can help a lot:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

**Hint:** Find a couple of similar right triangles (one of which you know a couple of sides).

Comment: (+1) Very nice! I didn't even think to use similar triangles.

Comment: @CameronBuie: I didn't think to use areas, so we're even :-)